# Addons are not installing

Tags: add-on

I am trying to install various addons to no avail. I have tried many, and they can't all be buggy.

I go to settings, click install from file, choose file, then select install from file again. Search for the addon and it isn't there. What am I doing wrong? I have also copied all of the content from the downloaded file and put it in a new file and saved as name.py. Still nothing shows up. And yes, the document starts with what it should start with, not html.

Comment: What **Supported Level** is selected at the top left?

Comment: I'm not sure where you mean. There are no numbers top left. I am using version 2.75 on a Mac.

Comment: In the user preferences window, addons tab, below the search box and above the categories: https://www.blender.org/manual/_images/Userpref_addons_en_oct20_2013.jpg

Comment: Ah i see. I looked on all of them and couldn't see it. I just put it directly in to the directory and it is now showing, but it is saying that there are two versions of it installed and can't launch. I am uninstalling the program and then putting the Haddon in manually. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Note that there are two folders for addons (at least on Windows), in Blender installation directory and in your user folder (on Windows in %appdata%). The addons Blender ships with are in the former, addons installed via the interface copy them to the latter.

Comment: Salvation. I just removed the Haddon from the user section of my computer. Not it all works great. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: See here: http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html#osx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your addons are zip files, then it is best to unzip them and place them in the addons directory. For Windows it is (where you installed Blender)/Blender Foundation/Blender 2.75/2.75/scripts/addons directory. Put your addons there, then restart Blender and it will show up in the User Prefs.

Comment: It's not necessary to restart Blender, `F8` should do the trick.

Comment: I just did what you said and now it is showing, but it says that two versions of it are now installed and I can't use it. What I am going to do is uninstall the whole program and reinstall it. Then just put it straight in to the directory like you suggested and hopefully it will work then.

Comment: It worked. I also had to remove the Haddon from my library user section on my Mac too. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

for me, not even moving the extracted file to the addons folder worked. I just extracted it, went to the .py file, and installed that